# How to implement quicksort using iterator format?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I tried to implement [this](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~lacher/courses/COP4531/lectures/sorts/slide09.html) code with iterators in C++. It works fine for e.g. std::less<>() as comparator but gives incorrect results when using std::greater<>(). Is my implementation wrong?

```
template <typename RandomIt, typename Compare>
void QuickSort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare compare)
{
    if (std::distance(first, last) <= 1) return;
    RandomIt bound = Partition(first, last, compare);
    QuickSort(first, bound);
    QuickSort(bound, last);
}

template <typename RandomIt, typename Compare>
RandomIt Partition(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare compare)
{
    auto pivot = std::prev(last, 1);
    auto i = first;
    for (auto j = first; j != pivot; ++j)
        if (compare(*j, *pivot))
            std::swap(*i++, *j);
    std::swap(*i, *pivot);
    return i;
}
```

Edit:

Example input, using `std::greater`:
`1, 2, 3`
Expected:
`3, 2, 1`
Actual:
`1, 2, 3`

Comment: `gives incorrect results`, `Is my implementation wrong?` Well, is the algorithm supposed to give incorrect results?

Comment: Well, even a quick glance shows differences between your implementation and the code you copied. `QuickSort(bound, last);` should be `QuickSort(bound + 1, last);` for instance.

Comment: The referenced algorithm uses also a less-than/eqal-as operator. This *may* be important.

Comment: Related to the stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452614/quicksort-algorithm-cormen-gives-stackoverflow

Comment: The pivot element is in the referenced algorithm the last element, in your code it is the second last.

Comment: QuickSort(first, bound); isn't passing compare

Comment: What are the incorrect results? (What was the input and actual output? I suppose we can infer the expected output in this case...)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, for this type of development, you need a unit-test framework and a debugger to step through the code. In particular the latter should be your prime learning objective for now, because problems like this are way easier to solve with that skill.

Comment: Your code will crash of stack overflow for certain inputs. You **must** use `bound+1`. What input gives incorrect results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### QuickSort:

```
/*
Description : QuickSort in Iterator format
Created     : 2019/03/04 
Author      : Knight-金 (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3547485)
Link        : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54976413/3547485

Ref: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~lacher/courses/COP4531/lectures/sorts/slide09.html
*/

template <typename RandomIt, typename Compare>
void QuickSort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare compare)
{
    if (std::distance(first, last)>1){
        RandomIt bound = Partition(first, last, compare);
        QuickSort(first, bound, compare);
        QuickSort(bound+1, last, compare);
    }
}

template <typename RandomIt, typename Compare>
RandomIt Partition(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare compare)
{
    auto pivot = std::prev(last, 1);
    auto i = first;
    for (auto j = first; j != pivot; ++j){
        // bool format 
        if (compare(*j, *pivot)){
            std::swap(*i++, *j);
        }
    }
    std::swap(*i, *pivot);
    return i;
}
```

---

### Test code:

```
std::vector<int> vec = {0, 9, 7, 3, 2, 5, 6, 4, 1, 8};

// less 
QuickSort(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), std::less<T>());

// greater 
QuickSort(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), std::greater<int>());
```

---

### Result:

[image]

Comment: Using `compare(*j, *pivot)<=0` gives opposite results than expected. I wanted Compare to be comparator like in std::sort, returning boolean value. Removing the `<=0` part solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There's the obvious problem that you aren't passing the `compare` to the inner `Quicksort`s, so presumably they are falling back to your default case.

```
QuickSort(first, bound, compare);
QuickSort(bound, last, compare);
```